# Prevent grub-install from trying to update nvram when triggered by apt

Tags: apt, grub2, uefi, debconf

On my machine running focal, `grub-install` fails if I don't pass it the `--no-nvram` flag. This is fine and I'm not looking for a way to fix that.

However, whenever apt updates my kernel or grub or whatever, it triggers a run of `grub-install` which then fails.

The only thing I could find was the debconf flag `grub2/update_nvram` which I've set to `false` as can be verified as follows:

```
# debconf-show grub-efi-amd64 |grep nvram
  grub2/update_nvram: false
```

However, when then running something like `apt reinstall grub-efi-amd64-signed`, grub-install fails because it does not get passed this option.

I can then fix it manually by running a `grub-install --no-nvram` myself but I'd rather not have to do that and have apt not error out every time something relating to the kernel or the bootloader gets updated (which is often :) ).

Is the debconf flag not being respected a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this parameter for the `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package?

e.g.:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<<'grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2/update_nvram boolean false'
```